# Mongoengine better query to update embedded documents in a listfield

Tags: python, mongodb, django-rest-framework, mongodb-query, mongoengine

Following is the function I wrote that sets "new_messages" flag to true of a members embedded document for a certain member in the conversation's document.

```
def check_and_update_new_messages_flag(self, pk, user):
    conversation = Conversation.objects.with_id(pk)
    if conversation is None:
        raise ConversationNotFoundException
    messages = Message.objects(conversation=pk).count()
    messages_viewed_by_user = Message.objects(conversation=pk, viewed_by=user).count()
    if messages == messages_viewed_by_user:
        for index, member in enumerate(conversation.members):
            if member.user == user:
                member = Members()
                member.user = user
                conversation.members[index] = member
                conversation.save()
        conversation.update()
```

I'm creating a Members object and replacing the members object at the index where the match occurs, only to update the new_messages flag to false(that's set as default in the model). Is there a better query to perform this task. I don't want the extra loops and the if statements so as to make this function more efficient.

EDIT: 
the models:

```
class Members(EmbeddedDocument):
    user = ReferenceField(User)
    new_messages = BooleanField(default=False)


class Conversation(Document, MboBaseDocument):
    opportunity = ReferenceField(Opportunity)
    members = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Members))
    counts = EmbeddedDocumentField(Counts)
    status = StringField(required=True, default='active', regex='closed|active')
    responded_on = IntField(required=True)
    created_by = ReferenceField('User', required=True)
    updated_at = IntField()
```

Also, sample document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55c37053aee967157371372e"),
    "opportunity" : ObjectId("55a3907c8c5bf672f4ad31b8"),
    "members" : [ 
        {
            "user" : ObjectId("5579a6b38c5bf602374b9a0b"),
            "new_messages" : true
        }, 
        {
            "user" : ObjectId("abcdef12345abcdef1234503"),
            "new_messages" : true
        }, 
        {
            "user" : ObjectId("5581168c45910c43912e6a01"),
            "new_messages" : true
        }
    ],
    "counts" : {
        "members" : 3,
        "messages" : 6
    },
    "status" : "active",
    "responded_on" : NumberLong(1438871635000),
    "created_by" : ObjectId("abcdef12345abcdef1234503"),
    "updated_at" : NumberLong(1439194817000)
}
```

Comment: Getting a little lost on following the logic here. Can you edit to show the class definitions involved here as well please. Also not sure what is going on with the `Members` here. You say you are replacing it. If so then why? Just to set one property?

Comment: Yes. that is the issue. I have to set new_messages flag to false. I can't figure out the mongoengine query to do that. I have added the models.